# unable to read message.properties file using EAP-7.2.0 and JSF

Tags: java, xml, jboss

I am trying to read the message.properties using JBoss EAP 7.2 but it is not happening. same Source code is working JBoss 7.1.

I had tried to add javax.faces-2.3.8.jar,javax.servlet-api-4.0.0.jar file but still, it is not reading properties file.

The same source of code is working with JBoss 7.1.

Comment: i  am  using faces-config.xml file   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.3" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd">
   <name>NameChecker</name>
   <application>
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>messages</base-name>
         <var>messages</var>
      </resource-bundle>
   </application>
</faces-config>

Answer (score 0):

Make `messages.properties` file in `src/main/resources/com/myproject/` with content eg.:

```
message = This is "message"
message.test1 = This is "message.test1"
message.test2 = This is "message.test2"
```

Load it in your JSF page locally like:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="com.myproject.messages" var="msg"/>
```

or globally like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>com.myproject.messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
       </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

And read property like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['message.test1']}" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working. I have implemented  same.